# How to Order a list and group by the list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a static List which I want to print at the end.

```
 class User 
    {
          int ID {get;set;}
          string status {get; set;}
          DateTime startTime {get;set;}
          int groupId {get;set;}
    }
```

I want to maintain the list of users in memory and print at the end. 
Now the list can have data like:

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();
userList.Add( new User{ ID = 1, ..., groupId = 1 } );
userList.Add( new User{ ID = 2, ..., groupId = 1 } );
userList.Add( new User{ ID = 3, ..., groupId = 2 } );
userList.Add( new User{ ID = 4, ..., groupId = 1 } );
userList.Add( new User{ ID = 5, ..., groupId = 3 } );
```

I want to group this data, which I can do using `userList.GroupBy(x => x.groupID)`, I get the `Enumberable<ID, List<User>>()`. Sorry, in the grouped lists i want to check if any of the Users have the status == fail , then i want to print all the Users information if status == true ,then i want to print only the userId's or names. For this i'm doing

```
groupedList.Any(x => x.status == fail)
```

But I want my output being sorted by startTime and then I want the result to be grouped by the Id

```
var result = userList.GroupBy(x=> x.groupID).OrderByDescending(x => x.startTime).ToList();
```

And then, I want my result when I print like

```
startTime - 10.00 groupId - 1 ,id - 1, ....status - fail ... more properties 
startTime - 10.00 groupId - 1, id - 2, .... status - pass ...
startTIme - 10.00 groupId - 1, id - 4, status - pass 
startTiem = 10.00 groupId - 2, id - 3, status - pass (just this info)
starttime - 9.50  groupId - 3, id - 5, status - fail ... more info 
starttime - 9.50  groupid - 3, id - 6, status - pass ... (still more info. as group has a fail case)
```

If I use the linq query above, it does not give the same output. Please suggest on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you don't want to group at all - your list has 5 elements and your output as well. You just want to order by multiple properties. This should work, then:

```
userList.OrderByDescending(x => x.startTime).ThenBy(x => x.groupId).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Glorfindel, I edited my question. I actually want to group them because if any user within the group has a status = fail then i want to print more information or else (status = pass), i will just print minimum information.

Comment: OK, but it is still not clear because the sample input you provide doesn't match the desired output. E.g. there's only one record with ID = 1 in the input, but two of them in the output.

Comment: Ok, so about the ID, my intention is if within a group any item has a fail case then i want to display the exception/ reason why it failed processing .. if its a pass (all users within a group) have a pass, i just want to display that the user info with pass status ...So, i'm still displaying all the list items. My only intention with grouping them by GroupID is to get the status of all the users within that group.